# Resource has a non-consistent extension with its actual content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was using Dareboost (SEO) and got this error and I couldn't find anywhere what the solution is so I thought I'd give this a try.

> **Resource has a non-consistent extension with its actual content.**
>
> The extension of a resource allows to identify easily its content
>   type. You have no reason to indicate a different extension of the
>   actual content type of the resource.
>
> For instance, the file resource.js must use a Content-Type HTTP header
>   equals to application/javascript. You can check the Content-Type HTTP
>   header value using a debug tool like Firebug.
>
> This page contains one resource uses an extension that is not
>   consistent with its Content-Type HTTP header:
>
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/0.9.6/build/packaged/css/semantic.min.css
>   (detected: text/plain; charset=utf-8 | recommended: text/css)

**The relevant code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js" ng-app="developerBlog">
  <head>
    <link Content-Type="text/css" data-require="semantic-ui@*" data-semver="0.9.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/0.9.6/build/packaged/css/semantic.min.css" />
  </head>
```

Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a completion to what Quentin said, there are some services which offer raw github files with the proper Content-Type.

https://rawgit.com/ is one of them.

RawGit serves raw files directly from GitHub with proper Content-Type headers.

And of course you can keep it free, or if you want stability and things you can go for paid plans.

I didn't recommend using this kind of services, but it's your choice.

Or at least don't use this in production. In dev environment it looks like a reasonable idea.

Answer (score 2):

Github is claiming your stylesheet is written in plain text (i.e. not CSS).

Don't use raw.githubusercontent.com as a hosting provider. That isn't what Github intend it for, and it isn't well suited for the job.

Comment: So I could copy it down into a new (local) CSS file and it should be fine?

Comment: Yes. (Unless your web server is horribly misconfigured, but that should be fixable)